# What does $k$ stand for in self-energy of renormalization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, renormalization, notation, feynman-diagrams

I'm reading "Renormalization" by John C. Collins, and it doesn't introduce the $k$ term, but uses it anyway.  Here is an excerpt for clarification:

> "When all components of $k^\mu$ get large, this integral diverges logarithmically. It is the simplest example of an ultra-violet divergence."  This is in the section titled "One-loop self-energy in $\phi^3$ theory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k^\mu$ typically stands for the four momentum in quantum field theory. The integral is most likely $d^4 k$.

The difference between $k$ and $p$: In a process in QFT we often have "real" momenta, which are the momenta of the incoming and outgoing particles. It seems like these are denoted $p$ in your book.

In addition, the expression for the cross section (or probability) can have integrals over $k$, you can understand them two ways:

- They come from taking fourier transforms, so they are just an integration variable,
- They are the momenta of internal lines / internal particles in a Feynman diagram

If a diagram has no loops, then it has none of these internal momenta. A diagram with $n$ loops has $n$ extra momentum variables that correspond to internal lines in a feynman diagram. When I say internal, I mean lines which are connected to other lines at both verticies. The momentum of internal lines is not measurable.

Comment: To add to this - considering the context, $k^\mu$ is most likely the four-momentum of the particle going around a loop in a Feynman diagram.

Comment: Are you sure?  Then why do they use $p$?  I thought $p$ was the momentum.  Then what is $p$?  The book uses $p$ to differentiate by momentum.

Comment: I edited to clarify. $p$ is the external momentum. $k$ can be seen as just a fourier transform integration variable, but it also has an interpretation as momentum of internal lines in a Feynman diagram.